# Desktop computer build review

Tags: desktop-computer

Please give your 2 cents, if and what to change/add.
Main mission is development and gaming.
Is everything will work together?
Which cooling should i add?

Thanks

MSI MPG x670e Carbon

AMD Ryzen 9 7900x unlocked

CORSAIR vengence DDR5 4X32GB 5600 Mhz CL40

MSI RTX 4060ti 16GB

EVGA supernova 1000 G7

WD black SN850X 2TB

Comment: This is off topic here (it is, effectively a shopping recommendation).